# Why it seems as there is no JavaScript code until I scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just started using javascript, and I do not understand why my javascript code doesn't works until I start to scroll a little bit(so I see my logo and my menu page like there is no Javascript code).

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".textLogo").css({
    'font-size': 690 - scrollPos + '%'
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.menu').css({
    opacity: function() {
      var elementHeight = $(this).height();
      return 1 - (elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.textLogo {
  color: #1C1C1C;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 110px;
  padding: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  font-size: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 275px;
  opacity: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you have a bit too many questions all in 1 post

Comment: `$(window).scroll()` adds a listener for the `scroll` event. Why would you expect anything to happen before the event?

Comment: My bad, I just fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the code only works at the bottom of your `body` tag because you haven't written an event listener for the DOM Content loading, if you want to put it in the header or seperate file write like this.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".textLogo").css({
   'font-size' : 690 - scrollPos + '%'
  });
 });

 $(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.menu').css({
   opacity: function() {
    var elementHeight = $(this).height();
    return 1 - (elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight;
   }
  });
 })
});
```

> (so I see my logo and my menu page like there is no Javascript code)

This is because the code you've written won't be called until you start scrolling due to the event listener you've chosen to use.
If you can provide the HTML to be tested this would be useful.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I think the question has been editted since answers have been posted.

Comment: "my javascript code doesn't works until I start to scroll a little bit" I do not see any code triggering the scroll events

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is in handlers for the `scroll` event, so it doesn't run until you scroll. If you want to force it to run when the page is loaded as well, you should trigger a scroll event in the code.

In that case, you should also put it inside `$(document).ready()` or put it at the end of the HTML, so that the elements it refers to will be loaded into the DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    $(".textLogo").css({
      'font-size': 690 - scrollPos + '%'
    });
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.menu').css({
      opacity: function() {
        var elementHeight = $(this).height();
        return 1 - (elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight;
      }
    });
  });
  
  $(window).scroll();
});
```

```css
.textLogo {
  color: #1C1C1C;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 110px;
  padding: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  font-size: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 275px;
  opacity: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

$(window).scroll(function()

You have used the .scroll function. This will mean it will activate your code when you scroll. Instead use $(window).load so it happens when the window loads. Hope this helps.